# Send over bluetooth python commands to another Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I want to connect two Raspberry Pi's with each other over Bluetooth.
Next, I want to send a command (in Python) to the other Raspberry Pi.

I want to use this for some home automation things for example to send a temperature from one pi via bluetooth to the other, without Wi-Fi.

I have been googling this for a very long time and couldn't find a good tutorial which worked for me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To connect two raspberry pi devices first you need to install following packages:

- connman
- pi-bluetooth
- bluetooth
- bluez
- python-bluez

Check if Bluetooth is enabled with command "hciconfig -a".
Example output when Bluetooth is TURNED OFF:

```
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: UART
        BD Address: B8:27:EB:9D:51:6B  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
        DOWN
        RX bytes:668 acl:0 sco:0 events:34 errors:0
        TX bytes:423 acl:0 sco:0 commands:34 errors:0
        Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
        Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3
        Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF
        Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
```

You can enable it with a command "connmanctl enable bluetooth". Now when you check again with "hciconfig -a" you should see something like this

```
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: UART
        BD Address: B8:27:EB:9D:51:6B  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
        UP RUNNING
        RX bytes:1385 acl:0 sco:0 events:75 errors:0
        TX bytes:1193 acl:0 sco:0 commands:75 errors:0
        Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
        Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3
        Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF
        Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
        Name: 'raspberrypi'
        Class: 0x6c0000
        Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Audio, Telephony
        Device Class: Miscellaneous,
        HCI Version: 4.1 (0x7)  Revision: 0x8b
        LMP Version: 4.1 (0x7)  Subversion: 0x6119
        Manufacturer: Broadcom Corporation (15)
```

To pair both raspberries follow instructions from the section "Using the Command Line" on [this site](https://bluedot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pairpipi.html)

If you want to communicate using python you can look at the code in [this repository](https://gist.github.com/keithweaver/3d5dbf38074cee4250c7d9807510c7c3)